# Does banning from answers in one Stack Exchange community affect all the other Stack Exchange communities?

Tags: support, post-ban

I started using Stack Exchange not long ago.

Does banning from answers in one Stack Exchange community affect all the other Stack Exchange communities?

Comment: It's my fault I didn't read what is post-ban about. So I was thinking it's about posting new questions and I see that there is a question-ban tag but there is no answer-ban tag so I used the banning tag

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, it does not. Reputation, flag, review and quality bans are per site.

So if you're quality banned on Stack Overflow you might still be able to post on other sites with different topics: Your cooking concerns can go on [Seasoned Advice](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), your dual boot concerns [Super User](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic), to name a few. Your practical programming concerns need to stay at bay.

Don't make it a habit to hit the bans on all sites you participate in. The bans are there to prevent that content with a similar or lower quality level enter the system. Ignoring the warnings from the system that posts need to be improved can lead to account suspension and if there is nothing worth keeping, even account deletion is an option.

Answer (score 7):

No, it does not.  Not unless you've done something *really* egregious. There has been a case of [a sitewide suspension](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/284807/account-temporarily-suspended-network-wide-for-the-next-10-years-and-cannot).

Comment: There have been *multiple* cases of network-wide suspensions. Note, though, that these must be put into place by staff. Moderators can only suspend you from the site they moderate. And these types of suspensions are all manual, which is totally unlike the post bans, which are automatic and cannot be controlled by moderators or staff.

Comment: Indeed, there was [another one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/776110/sendhelp) just this morning.

Comment: "The suspension period ends on Aug 5 '30 at 3:06." Yeesh!

Comment: @zcoop98 Ahem… see [User's suspension period has expired, but they're still suspended?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/327015/289905), and the linked question [Why not perma-ban instead of suspend an account for 275 years?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/319634/289905).